# When to actually use Freeze() for WPF controls?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

Should I set all brushes that I create or directly assign as background to Freeze? What about other user controls that I do not modify?

> A Freezable provides a Changed event to notify observers of any modifications to the object. Freezing a Freezable can improve its performance, because it no longer needs to spend resources on change notifications. A frozen Freezable can also be shared across threads, while an unfrozen Freezable cannot.

From this it seems that if my application never does any change to the created brush then there is no difference performance-wise whether I set freeze it or not. Am I correct?

Comment: You shouldn't create brushes on the fly if you can help it. Put them in a resource dictionary and merge the resource dictionary. Such resources are frozen. At least in theory frozen freezables are more efficient. Whether this makes any noticeable difference in practice will depend on what you're doing with your unfrozen stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as you can, you should put any brushes which will see significant usage in one or more resource dictionaries.

So long as you don't make part of the brush depend on something variable, these will be automatically frozen.  Merge them in app.xaml so these can be used throughout your application.

For most WPF developers, this is the most common usage of freeze they will come across and is done automatically.

If you use a freezable that is unfrozen then the changed event will be subscribed to in order to drive potential changes to the view. If you freeze it then this event will not be subscribed to and this is therefore more efficient.  You would have to use a lot of unfrozen freezables before you're likely to notice such a problem though.

If you do a lot of graphics processing such as writing a game then passing freezables such as dynamically built geometries from background threads to the UI is likely to be of interest and significant. You can, however, write a lot of business applications and never need to do this sort of thing.

There is a rather limited set of things you can freeze - they must inherit from freezable.  Usercontrols do not.
If you read the list, you'll probably spend more time thinking "what's that one" than "ah yes I can see myself freezing a.... ThumbButtonInfo ".

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.freezable?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 1):

> Should I set all brushes that I create or directly assign as background to Freeze?

Yes, assuming you don't intend to modify them. This saves the system from having to monitor them for modifications, to update their corresponding unmanaged resources that are used under the hood.

As freezing a `Freezable` objects provides this performance benefit, it's considered a best practice to freeze them whenever you know they won't be modified.

If you for example create a `Brush` on a background thread, you must freeze it in order to be able to assign it to a property of an `UIElement` on the UI thread.

Make sure that you check the value the `CanFreeze` property as explained in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/freezable-objects-overview).

You can freeze XAML resources using the [PresentationOptions:Freeze Attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/presentationoptions-freeze-attribute).

Comment: What about color added through xaml?

Comment: A `Color` is an immutable `struct` and cannot be explicitly frozen. Or what to you mean?

Comment: You can freeze XAML resources using the [PresentationOptions:Freeze Attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/presentationoptions-freeze-attribute).